# The Alias directive will probably never match because it overlaps an earlier Alias

Tags: php, apache, localhost, cgi

I am trying to get cgi work on my localhost server.
Firstly I have add virtual local host.
I have conf file /etc/apache2/sites-available/myage.com.conf 
Here is content of this file.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName mypage.com
        ServerAlias www.mypage.com
        ServerAdmin admin@mypage.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/mypage.com/public_html
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/www/mypage.com/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/var/www/mypage.com/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

And I am getting error while restarting apache2 service

```
 [Fri Jan 16 09:06:12.422793 2015] [alias:warn] [pid 12733] AH00671: The ScriptAlias directive in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mypage.com.conf at line 31 will probably never match because it overlaps an earlier ScriptAlias.
```

Answer (score 6):

Place the `ScriptAlias` and `<Directory>...</Directory>` directives that you've declared, *inside* of the `VirtualHost` tag block; your above file currently has them declared as server-wide as they are outside of it.

The `ScriptAlias` overlapping warning is being caused by `ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/` already being declared server-wide earlier on in a configuration file as Apache starts up.